# Change plot transparency

Tags: matlab, plot, transparency

If we have two image objects `imageObj1` and `imageObj2` and we've plotted them on one axes like the following:

```
figure;
hAxes = axes();
imageHandle1 = imshow(imageObj1);
hold(hAxes,'on');
imageHandle2 = imshow(imageObj2);
```

Then I can change the transparency of any of the two plotted images on the axes by changing the `AlphaData` property like the following:

```
set( imageHandle2, 'AlphaData', 0.6 ); %// Change transparency to 0.6
```

All this previous codes and methods are for images, but I need some way to change he transparency of plots not images.

**The question:**
 if I've a plot handle called `pHandle`, How can I edit the transparency of the plot of this handle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line series objects do not support transparency (alpha) values.

Read [this](http://www.mathworks.fr/support/solutions/en/data/1-2STXLP/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-2STXLP) for a hint about a workaround.

Hope it helps!

Comment: But this method is too slow !, is there any other faster method of doing so ?